# Public IP Address to be tested legally?

Tags: scan

According to [this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-ok-to-scan-a-public-IP-address):

> Scanning a public IP address can be a cyber crime.

But there are a few public IPs that can be used for testing purposes such as

- `45.33.32.156` which is belong to http://scanme.nmap.org/
- `176.28.50.165` for http://testphp.vulnweb.com/

Is there anything else? I would like to have something in e.g. the range `x.x.x.1-10`.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "what product/service does X (or, allows me to do X)?" are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

## Depends on what you want to "test"

If all you care about is port scanning, then the two above-mentioned addresses are perfectly fine. It demonstrates how `nmap` works, and you can use these hosts to try out some further scanning techniques (Service Detection, OS Detection, etc.)

You can also port scan some internal devices, such as:

- PC
- Laptop
- Smart Phone
- Game Console
- Router (Internal & External IP)
- Printer
- "Smart" Devices (Fridge, TV, Lightbulb, etc.)

Since you are the owner of these devices, you can scan them freely as you want. You'd be surprized what you can discover there.

## What if you want to "test" more invasively?

Port Scans are kind of a grey area, depending on the applied jurisdiction. Some consider it a crime, some don't regulate it at all. And while it may not be legal, a lot of port scans happen all the time over the internet. That doesn't make it alright of course, and you should not interpret my previous statement as "It's alright to do it". The golden rule of ethical hacking is to never attack a system you don't have permission to attack.

But what if you want to do more invasive testing? You have several options:

### Install a local vulnerable system

You can install intentionally vulnerable distributions such as [Metasploitable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/files/Metasploitable2/) or insecure services like [OWASP Juice Shop](https://owasp.org/www-project-juice-shop/). These are designed to be learning tools for people interested in learning penetration testing. Since these run locally on your own system, you can freely test them however you want.

### Use a remote vulnerable system

Services like [Hack The Box](https://www.hackthebox.eu/) offer similar vulnerable "boxes", which you can attack within the permissible parameters of their EULA. These are generally designed as explorative teaching tools, meaning you will learn new things as you try to exploit them.

### Participate in a Bug Bounty program

Some companies offer bugs for vulnerabilities in their programs or services. It's possible that some company explicitly allows you to test for e.g. XSS vulnerabilities on their service. In that case, you do have explicit permission to test that.

Answer (score -7):

Port scanning can never be considered cyber crime, because is the service that responds on that port and protocol that is considered the target; Port and protocol are the attack vehicle, not the attack itself.
Any node that keeps a door open is a node that offers a service: All depends on how you query it and the information you get.
When your browser connects to a web server, before getting the page, it performs a port scan on that server.

Comment: "Port Scanning can never be considered a cyber crime" - Don't give general legal statements like this, especially if you don't know OP's jurisdiction. And also especially if it's blatantly wrong.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, it is very much a crime.

Comment: And you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a port scan is. Client connections to a port is not a port scan under any definition.